# Border not consistent with internal or external css but consistent with inline css

Tags: html, css

The border around my div is not consistent.

HTML code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=\, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique, dolore.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX4yV.png)

I get the same output when my CSS in internal but when I include inline CSS, the problem is fixed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=\, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style = "border: 1px solid black">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique, dolore.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaQns.png)

Why is this happening?

Comment: Your code works fine for me in both scenarios! Do you have any other style on the div element? If so, please share it.

Comment: @philale No all the code I have I pasted, I've asked someone else and it works fine for him as well. I don't understand how we can have the same code but get different outputs.

Comment: Thats weird, maybe try it in a different browser.

Comment: Inline priority is high so this will overrule css in jour stylesheet. Do you have somewhere in your stylesheet set  a border 2px?

Comment: I don't. When I remove the div in the html file but keep the div styling in css file I get a straight horizontal line which doesn't make any sense. Then when I remove the div styling the straight line goes away.

Comment: The css above is ok https://jsfiddle.net/tmq8os65/ We cannot see what is inside your stylesheet. Maybe update your post with relevant css from your stylesheet? ## A bug in the viewport line, it is `content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem appeared to just be a browser issue, I ran the same code in safari rather than chrome and it worked. I reinstalled chrome and everything worked after that.